# Core Data Fetch Request Relationship Attribute Predicate

Tags: ios, core-data, nspredicate, nsfetchrequest

I have Father Entity. Father has a one-to-many relationship with Child. Child has attributes and one of them is name.

I want to perform a fetch request to get:
Father.name = "Joe"
and out of the fathers named joe I want to fetch those that have a child named Ken:
Child.name = "Ken"

So my main objective is to find Ken whose father's name is Joe.

I tried some compound predicates and other things but not luck yet.

Any idea how I can solve this?

thank you

Answer (score 6):

Assuming you want the child:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"father.name = %@ AND name = %@", @"Joe", @"Ken"]
```

should work

Comment: So where am I specifying the Child entity in this predicate? thanks